# How to put pdf file into specific folder after sending it through email

Tags: php

Here's my code for generating pdf and send it through email

$dompdf->set_paper($customPaper);

```
    $dompdf->render();
    ob_end_clean();
    $file = $dompdf->output();
    file_put_contents($pdfname,$file);
    $name = 'sample';
    $subject = 'sample subject';
    $body = 'Hello '.$empname.' , here\'s your payslip';
    if(!empty($email)){

        $mail = new PHPMailer();

        // smtp settings
        $mail->isSMTP();
        $mail->Mailer = "smtp";
        $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
        $mail->Username = "sample@gmail.com";  // gmail address
        $mail->Password = "sample123";         // gmail password
        $mail->Port = 587;
        $mail->IsHTML(true);
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
        $mail->SMTPOptions = array(
            'ssl' => array(
                'verify_peer' => false,
                'verify_peer_name' => false,
                'allow_self_signed' => true
            )
        );


        // email settings
        $mail->isHTML(true);
        $mail->setFrom($email,$name);             
        $mail->addAddress($email);                  
        $mail->Subject = ($subject);    
        $mail->Body = $body;
        $mail->AddAttachment($pdfname);                     [check the picture][1]

        if($mail->send()){
            $status = "success";
            $response = "Email is sent!";
        } else {
            $status = "failed";
            $response = "Something is wrong: <br/>". $mail->ErrorInfo;
        }
```

I want to put the generated pdf to the specific folder to be organized, because it just appear somewhere. thankyou very much for your help

Comment: are you asking how to move a file to another folder using PHP? Pretty sure you can google that already.

Comment: In your mail client? Or on your server? Or when you save the attachment from the mail?

Comment: No sir, after generating pdf  using dompdf it send to the receiver through email and when I look at the project folder, generated pdf just appear somewhere. I want to put it to a specific folder I just don't know where exactly in my code to put a path for generating pdf

Comment: Friendly note: What makes you think everyone commenting is a "sir"? Not everyone is, or wants to be thought of as one. I suggest using neutral language or referring to people directly by their usernames, before you accidentally offend someone. :-)

Comment: @brombeer at my project folder sir

Comment: If you are emailing people their payslips as attached PDFs, _please_ do not set SSL verify to false.

Comment: @ADyson I'm sorry if you feel that way :(

Comment: I didn't say I was offended, I said you should be careful before you offend someone in future. I thought the smiley face and the "friendly note" text was enough to tell you I wasn't upset myself. :-)

Comment: I think what @ADyson meant, that it also could be a "Madam" or even something totally different ;)

Comment: You already save the pDF with ``file_put_contents($pdfname,$file); ``
If you want to save the PDF elsewhere, just add a path to $PDFname. As an example: 

``file_put_contents('/tmp/' . $pdfname,$file); ``

Comment: @cyberbrain exactly what I meant.

Comment: @cyberbrain, a dog perharps!

Comment: `I just don't know where exactly in my code to put a path for generating pdf`...well the [documentation for file_put_contents](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) says the first parameter you send to it is _Path to the file where to write the data._ . So hopefully that answers your question.

Comment: @AlexHowansky thankyou for informing me about that but I'm having a hard time using ssl because there's an error I can't fix, Anyway this project is not that important I just did this for myself, I'm practicing coding. thank you

Comment: Nobody criticized your work

Comment: Thank you to all of you :) btw  I'm new here so you will always see me asking a question with simple and very basic solution for all of you, I'm starting to study coding and sometimes, I'm having a hard time searching problems that I encounter  lol :)